# Autocorrelation of random binary sequence

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation

For a true random sequence the zeroes and ones are equally likely to occur. So the mean is 1/2 and variance is 1/4.
Is there any other property of random sequence that I am missing?

I need to prove that the autocorrelation of a  true random sequence of bits is 0 for any no. of shifts to the right.

How do I  prove the above statement?

Comment: If you are assuming that each bit is independent of the others then this looks immediate

Comment: @Henry Can you please help me understand how is this immediate?

Comment: @Henry Hi. If it's not zero then that implies the original bit sequence( assumed to be truly random)  has some dependence among its bits ... Is that why?

Comment: That is saying the same thing as a contrapositive

Comment: @Henry How do I show that it will be nearly 0 for truly random sequences theoretically using the correlation formula? Some hints please.

Comment: If the zeroes and ones are equally likely to occur and are independent then the probability that the first bit is $0$ and the second $0$ is $\frac14$, similarly that the first bit is $0$ and the second $1$, that the first bit is $1$ and the second $0$, and that that the first bit is $1$ and the second $1$.  So you can calculate that the covariance is $0$ and the correlation is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The autocorrelation for a binary sequence $B=(b_1, b_2, \dots b_n)$ is
$$R_{BB}(i,j) = \mathbb{E}[b_ib_j] = \dfrac{1}{4}$$
The auto-covariance
$$ \mathbb{E}[b_ib_j] -\mathbb{E}[b_i] \mathbb{E}[b_j] $$
is $0$ because the expectations are $\mathbb{E}[b_i] = \mathbb{E}[b_j]  = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: Here I want to take the correlation of B and B shifted by k places to the right. I understand the expectation of each bit and pairwise bits. Let me call the new sequence B1 obtained from B by shifting k places to the right. Then Cov(B,B1) = 1/(N-k) [ sum{i=1 to N-k} (xi - E(x))(yi - E(y)) ] has to be zero. xi, yi represent the corresponding bits in the two sequence. How do I write this expression in terms of individual expections of bits ?